# Post a form value to Django rest framework to retrieve json

Tags: json, django, forms, post, django-rest-framework

How do i post a HTML form value from a django view to django-restframework view?

I am constructing a Django application. It has an app called 'API' from this app i configured the urls.py as

```
url(r'^programdetail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', ProgramDetail.as_view(), name='programdetail')
```

when i visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/programdetail/1/` The program detail whose primarykey is 1 is displayed. I used the following code

```
class ProgramDetail(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'test.html'

    def get(self, request, pk):
        pg = get_object_or_404(Program, pk=pk)
        serializer = ProgSerializer(pg)
        return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'data': pg.name})
```

Now i have a html form and a view to render it. The codes are

```
<body>
  <h1>Programs</h1>
   {% csrf_token %}

  <form action ="" method="GET" novalidate>
    <select name="pk">
       {% for program in programs %}
           <option value="{{ program.program_id }}">{{ program.name }}</option>
       {% endfor %}
     </select>
     <button type="submit">View</button>
   </form>
</body>
```

and the view i used is

```
def programsform(request):
    progs = Program.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'allprograms.html', {'programs':progs})
```

This view gives me a HTML form that shows a drop down list of program names. Now the question is about action attribute. To which URL do i POST or GET these values to construct a the URL like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/programdetail/{the posted program_id}` and display them in my template.

I tried posting these values to the same `ProgramDetail` class and wrote a `post()` method like this

```
def post(self, request, pk):
    program = get_object_or_404(Program, pk=pk)
    serializer = ProgSerializer(program)
    return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'program': program})
```

But nothing worked.  What is the solution for this? Can anyone help me in identifying the solution?

Comment: As previously explained, it doesn't make sense for your app to be posting to itself.

Comment: Then how do i achieve this. what i want is retrieve one json by using a HTML form that uses the primary key value. When submit is clicked it must make the call to the serilalizer and retrieve the json and display it. This is what i want. Is there an alternate way?

Comment: I understand that what you want to do is have a form where you select a program, as as a result you are redirected to the GET URL for that program, correct?

Comment: Yes absolutely. Any solution ??